# Wpf datagrid event to listen to binding changes

Tags: c#, wpf

how can I configure the datagrid to fire an event every time the property binded to ItemsSource changes?

Comment: Why you want to configure the datagrid for that? Just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the class you bind on and fire it when the property gets set.

Comment: Your property has to sent notification when it get changes (via implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your class) .

Comment: uh, I was late :-(

Comment: I need to programmaticaly change column sort when data changes.

Comment: sorry, I don't see bond between your Q and your last comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did this:

```
<DataGrid
   ItemsSource="{Binding RecordList, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
   TargetUpdated="GridResult_TargetUpdated"
   ...

private void GridResultado_TargetUpdated(object sender, System.Windows.Data.DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
    //my sort routine
}
```

Comment: Works perfect for me!